# Dont understand the result of conversion of type double to type byte

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

Hello i had task from my book to write this code

```
public class EkspKonverzija 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        byte b;
        int i=257;
        double d= 323.142;

        b=(byte) i;
        System.out.println("i and b "+i+" "+b);

        i=(int) d;
        System.out.println("d and i "+d+" "+i);

        b=(byte) d;
        System.out.println("b and d "+b+" "+d);


    }
}
```

And result is:

> i and b 257 1
>
> d and i 323.142 323
>
> d and b 323.142 67

I understand why the result of first conversion is 1, and i also understand the second conversion, but i dont undetsand why is result 67 at last conversion, i cant figure it out so i need your help. Thanks

Comment: 323 - 256 = 67. That's why.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these are called [*Narrowing Primitive Conversion (§5.1.3)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

1. The conversation to `(byte)`:

   ```
          257 = 0000 0001 0000 0001
   ```

   Truncating the high byte gives:

   ```
   (byte) 257 = xxxx xxxx 0000 0001
   ```

   which is obviously 1.
2. The conversation from a floating point to an integer is always **round to zero**.
3. The conversation from `double` to `byte` happens in two steps:

   1. The `double` gets casted to an `int`, following the **round to zero** rule.

      ```
      (int) 323.142  ~~~>  323
      ```
   2. The `int` gets truncated to a byte.

      ```
      (byte) 323     ~~~~> 67

             323 = 0000 0001 0100 0011
      (byte) 323 = xxxx xxxx 0100 0011
                 = 67
      ```

Comment: Got it now, thank you a lot. This will help me, thanks!

Comment: @miljannet: You can accept this answer as the answer that helped you out. Click the checkmark under my score to do that.

Comment: I am still new to this site, i need to have atleast 15 points for that.

Comment: Oh, okay. I can't really remember that. Now you can :)

Comment: Actually it looks like you didn't or maybe undid it. Because it is not accepted.

Comment: I hope i did it now ?

Comment: Absolutely Perfect :)